# Are firebase events base64 encoded?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I referred the example [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions) to filter out duplicate events. I see that the event id contains `=` as well as `/` characters. Are the event id base64 encoded? This is creating issues at times as the document path becomes nested collection if a slash `/` is found in the id. But to my surprise I was not able to base64 decode them.

For example- 2 id which I could track are - `LJ79W2cT0inTJbzFEHH/Aw3i10M=` and `IQUaGYPQpdYZw3mT3dHRca/Q7tU=`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any definition of what an event ID in Cloud Functions looks like. You should treat them as opaque strings and not make any assumptions on their contents or the meaning of their contents beyond that if you get the same event ID multiple times, they represent the same event.

Comment: Thank you for the response there @Frank. 
Now because of this, I see errors like `Error: Value for argument "documentPath" must point to a document, but was "LJ79W2cT0inTJbzFEHH/Aw3i10M=". Your path does not contain an even number of components.` Should I explicitly escape the `/` ?

Comment: It sounds like you're using the event ID as a document or collection ID in Firestore, which indeed won't be possible if the ID contains a `/`. It's really hard to say what's going on though, so I recommend reading about [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and posting a (possibly new questions with a) [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a Trigger's EventId as document ID directly, since it can contain forward slashes.

You should remove the slashes first:

```js
exports.onGoodsUpdate = functions
    .database
    .ref("goods/{id}")
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const data = change.after.val() as Goods
        const repository = new GoodsReportRepository()
        const report: GoodsReport = {
            id: context.eventId.replace("/", ""),
            groupCode: data.code,
        }
        return repository.save(report)
    })
```